# How to run a function without window.onload wrapper

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, charts

Is there a way to run the below function without "window.onload"? I'm trying to load the chart without loading into the Body.

```
window.onload = function() {

var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas_pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData1,opts);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish. Is this technique a problem for some reason?

Comment: I'm using XHR to load a page that has a canvas in it. Since the page will load before the XHR page request is finish, I can't use window.onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need window.onload if you call this line (or load script containing this line) after mycanvas_pie in HTML.

```
<canvas id="mycanvas_pie"></canvas>
<script>
    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas_pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData1,opts);
</script>
```

will works.

Comment: I'm using XHR to load the page which has the "var myPie = ..." would I have to append it to the readyState function or is there a different way to load the new Chart?

Comment: You can pack the line into named function (e.g. AjaxPageLoad) and in onreadystatechange you call this function. Second option is let line into window.onload and in readystatechange call `window.onload();`. But don't forget second variant calls only last assigned onload function. If you rewrite onload event by event from another script (or plugin) it does not work. Because this variant 1 is better than variant 2.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code tries to get a DOM element by id ("mycanvas_pie"), it must be executed after the DOM is created.Otherwise it will not work because you cant get an element that does not exist. You can use a self invoked function which will invoke when the DOM is created.

```
(function(){
    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas_pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData1,opts);
})();
```

Its like executing the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // some code
});
```

Comment: I'm using XHR to load a page which has the canvas so I wanted to remove the "window.onload" since the page won't be finished loading before the whole page is.